# 2222: Index name is not unique (TimesTen)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing, timesten

I have created two indexes on different materialized views with the same name in TimesTen and now cannot drop neither of them. If try to I get the following error message:

```
2222: Index name is not unique
```

Could you please advise me how could I get rid of one (or at least both) of these indexes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't permit the creation of index with the same name in the same schema. Are your indexes in seperate schemas? if Yes, then please specify your schema.index_name while deletion.To check the schemas of index , you can query all_indexes.

select * from all_indexes where index_name = 'put your index name here';

Then you can log in to one of the schemas and run delete schema_name.index_name. It must be a privilege issue hence you are getting an error

Comment: Thank you for reply, yes my indexes are created on different schemas, however, if I specify schema name schema_name.indexName while deleting I get: "2223: Named index does not exist". I want to stress that I face this problem in Times Ten not in pure oracle, moreover, I forgot to mention that indexes are created on materialized views.

Comment: I haven't worked on timesten but this looks like privilege issue. Can u login to one of the schemas where this index is created and try 'drop index schema_name.index_name' ;

Comment: Thanks for the help, you are right that was a privilege issue!

Comment: @user2342436, although helpful, your answer does not actually answer the question in its current form. Can you edit it with the results of the findings in the comments above?

Answer (score 0):

To drop indexes for Materialized Views [or tables] of the same name in two different schemas, you need to either:

1. Log into the first schema and drop the MV index
   Log into the second schema and drop the MV index
2. As the instance administrator [the OS user who you installed TimesTen as]
   and qualify the index to be dropped by the schema. eg

   ttIsql yourDbDSN
   drop schema1.index;
   drop schema2.index;

Answer (score 0):

Specify the table name (or materialized view name) in the drop index query.

It should work.

Ex. like below.

```
DROP INDEX schema_name.index_name_01 FROM schema_name.table_name_01;
```